# Limit in two variables with two parameters

Tags: limits

I have to compute $a,b$ such that the limit
$$\lim_{x \to - \infty}ae^{-x}+be^{-2x}+(e^{-x}+e^{-2x})\log(1+e^x)$$
is finite. With the help of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$ I’m pretty sure that $a=-1$ and $b=0$ is a solution. But I’m not able to prove it in a rigorous way (I’m out of practice with the limit).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

As $y:=e^x\to0^+$, using [Landau's little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation),
$$\frac ay+\frac b{y^2}+\left(\frac1y+\frac1{y^2}\right)\ln(1+y)$$
$$=\frac{ay+b+(y+1)(y-y^2/2+o(y^2))}{y^2}$$
$$=\frac{b+(a+1)y+y^2/2+o(y^2)}{y^2}$$
has a finite limit iff $b=0$ and $a=-1$, the limit being then $1/2$.